# Google Apps Script CardService Switch value not in field inputs

Tags: google-apps-script

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/switch) for the Switch class in Google Apps Script suggests that this is the right way to create a switch:

```
var switchDecoratedText  = CardService.newDecoratedText()
  .setTopLabel("Switch decorated text widget label")
  .setText("This is a decorated text widget with a switch on the right")
  .setWrapText(true)
  .setSwitchControl(CardService.newSwitch()
      .setFieldName("form_input_switch_key")
      .setValue("form_input_switch_value")
      .setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction()
          .setFunctionName("handleSwitchChange")));
```

But despite the call to `setFieldName()` here, when I try this I don't see the switch value in the `formInputs` object, despite it including everything else on the card.

Is there some way to retrieve the value of a switch here?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't quite following the documentation - I was calling `setFieldName()` but not `setValue()`.  Once the switch has a value and is "on", you get a `event.commonEventObject.formInputs.form_input_switch_key[""].stringInputs.value` which is an array `["form_input_switch_value"]`.  If the switch is "off", the `form_input_switch_key` is missing from the `formInputs` object.